# Upgrade BillingClient 3 to 5

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using BillingClient 3 and now I need to upgrade to 5. I am getting an error in the line of code I shared below. How can I solve the problem?

[image]

```
@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
    //if item newly purchased
    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
        handlePurchases(purchases);
    }
    //if item already purchased then check and reflect changes
    else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
        Purchase.PurchasesResult queryAlreadyPurchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(SUBS);
        List<Purchase> alreadyPurchases = queryAlreadyPurchasesResult.getPurchasesList();
        if(alreadyPurchases!=null){
            handlePurchases(alreadyPurchases);

        }
    }
    //if purchase cancelled
    else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
    }
    // Handle any other error msgs
    else {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error "+billingResult.getDebugMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}`
```

Comment: They've revamped the entire SDK surface objects and overall subscriptions/purchaes paradigms, this is largely considered a painful update - definitely take your time. I would recommend targeting v6 as v5 will likely be deprecated and sunsetted soon. Either way, they do provide a lot of documentation https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate-gpblv6#5-or-6